# Django Python - Failed To Create Process When Creating New Virtual Env - The System Can Not Find The Path Specified

Tags: django, pip, virtualenv

I just learned python framework, django. I installed python v3.6.4, the latest pip (10.0.1), and the latest virtual env (15.1.0), but when creating a new virtual env, i got this message

`failed to create process.
The system can not find the path specified
The system can not find the path specified
The system can not find the path specified`

Please help me, what should i do ? Thanks

Comment: can you show commands that you executed

Comment: this is the command :
`mkvirtualenv myEnv`

i have try other command like: `virtualenv myEnv`

but i got that error too